# Modification of second fundamental theorem of calculus

Tags: calculus, definite-integrals

Let $f:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be continuous and let $F:[a, b]\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$ be defined by $F(x)=\int_a^x f(t) \,dt$. Then $F$ is differentiable whose derivative is $f$.

Now define $G$ on $[a, b]$ by $G(x)=\int_x^b f(t)\, dt$.

It can be shown, **following the proof of above theorem**, that $G$ is differentiable with derivative $-f$ (is this correct)?  However, I wanted to see, how the assertion about $G$ follows from that of $F$ without following the proof of assertion for $F$? Any hint?

Comment: Use $-G = \intop_b^x f(x) dx$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**HINT**

Note that
$$
A = \int_a^b f(t) dt
$$
is a constant and
$$
G(x) = \int_x^b f(t) dt = \int_a^b f(t) dt - \int_a^x f(t) dt = A - F(x)
$$

Answer (score 4):

Here's a hint: start with the fact that if $a \le x \le b$ then
$$\int_a^b f(t) \, dt = \int_a^x f(t) \, dt + \int_x^b f(t) \, dt
$$
which is a simple consequence of the definition of definite integrals.